# Excel-VBA: Change the Filter of only one Pivot-Table

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table, vba

i'm searching for a soluton for this:

I have a wookbook, in which are multiple sheets, in which are multiple pivot-tables. I simply want to change the Filter of only one specific pivot-table.

If I use the ActiveSheet-Method this seems to work but this Sheet is not active when I start this code, so I try to change this filter by adressing it:

```
Sub Jahresübergang2()

Dim Jahresuebergang2 As Worksheet
    Set Jahresuebergang2 = Worksheets(11)

Jahresuebergang2.PivotTables("Name of Pivot Table").PivotFields("[Incident resolved].[Period].[Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("[Incident resolved].[Period].[Year].&[2017]")

End Sub
```

I get Runtime-Error 1004: Run-time error '1004': Method 'PivotTables' of object '_worksheet' failed

It's like I am doint the wrong object-syntax to change filters of only one table.

Here is what the makro recorder is doing:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Name of Pivot Table").PivotFields( _
        "[Incident resolved].[Year].[Year]").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Name of Pivot Table").PivotFields( _
        "[Incident resolved].[Year].[Year]").CurrentPageName = _
        "[Incident resolved].[Year].&[2017]"
End Sub
```

You see: I don't want to use the activesheet method, due this sheet isn't active when I want to perform this makro.

Thanks a lot for your help!

PS: I use Excel 365

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, can you fire up the macro recorder and make the change manually, and post the resulting code above?

Comment: Hi, I added your requested information.

Comment: Did my answer solve the issue?

Comment: No it did not solve my issue. In the meantime I did try another code: I try to use Tabelle14.Activate to activate the sheet. The only problem may be that this sheet will be active during the makro-process. I solved this with Application.ScreenUpdating = False (Code) and then Application.ScreenUpdating = True, so activation won't be updated on the screen. This solves my problem. But thanks for your answer anyway :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my Solution:

TabelleX.Activate (X for the Number of the Sheet)

to activate the sheet. The only problem may be that this sheet will be active on the monitor during the makro-process. I solved this with:

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
(Code) 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

so activation won't be updated on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has [Incident resolved].**[Period]**.[Year] whereas the macro recorder has [Incident resolved].**[Year]**.[Year]

Change your code to say  [Incident resolved].**[Year]**.[Year] and try again.